# Multiple errors: Values not connecting to dictionary str (the keys), and need to fill an empty dictionary with said values

Tags: python

I need to loop through the creation of dictionaries that will house values (float32), that I can eventually put into a dictionary where the key is the name, and the value is a 4D array with these values going into the first dimension.

Tried printing out the shapes, and types for the "turb", "gtg", "level" and "climo_grib" dictionaries to make sure they are all the same. Can't seem to figure it out.

```
validfiles00 = glob.glob(gribdir + '*18f0*')
validfiles06 = glob.glob(gribdir + '*00f0*')
validfiles12 = glob.glob(gribdir + '*06f0*')
validfiles18 = glob.glob(gribdir + '*12f0*')

levels = [1000,850,700,500,400,300,250,200,150,100]
hrs = ['00','06','12','18']
gtg = collections.OrderedDict()

for hr in hrs:
    for lev in levels:
        gtg['gtg{0}_{1}'.format(hr,lev)] = np.empty((len('validfiles'+hr), len(levels), 721, 1440),dtype=np.float32)

index = 0
climo_grib = {}
level = {}
turb = {}

for grb in validfiles00:
    for lev in levels:
        for hr in hrs:
            climo_grib['climo_grib{0}_{1}'.format(hr,lev)] = pygrib.index(grb,"level")
            for cg in climo_grib:
                level['level{0}_{1}'.format(hr,lev)] = climo_grib[cg].select(level=lev)
            for l in level:
                turb['turb{0}_{1}'.format(hr,lev)] = level.values()
            for t in turb:
                for g in gtg:
                    gtg[g][index:,:,:] = turb[t]

                    index = index + 1
```

This particular order of code gives the error: "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."

Ultimately, I want a dictionary (such as the above gtg), or some set to call from with a 4D array as the value with the values from the loop as the 1st dimension. For example, if I were to call gtg['gtg00_1000'], I want to get actual floating numbers as output.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Where*, exactly, did the error occur?  The `for cg` and `for l` loops near the end don't seem like they're doing what you want, since you're overwriting the same dictionary entry on each iteration - only the value from the final iteration gets kept.

Comment: The ValueError came from: gtg[g][index:,:,:] = turb[t]. So you're saying the level.values might be getting overwritten due to the loops?

Comment: To expand, level[l] should have floating numbers associated with it. When I print level[l] or level.values(), I just get the details attached to the file, but not the numbers  associated with it...